# How do I get window number from CFTypeRef in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

```
CFTypeRef focusedWindow;
AXUIElementCopyAttributeValue(
        frontMostApp, kAXFocusedWindowAttribute, (CFTypeRef *)&focusedWindow
);
```

in this case, How do I get window number from `focusedWindow`?

Window number is like `[[NSApp mainWindow] windowNumber]`

Comment: A CFTypeRef is just a generic CF object; it's the counterpart to Foundation's NSObject. You cannot expect just any CFType to have a window number, because that doesn't make sense for most objects. An AXWindow or AXUIElement might, but, well, Chuck already said it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an AXUIElement, and unfortunately, [you can't get its window number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742890/cgwindowid-from-axuielement) AFAIK.

Comment: Thank you. The link is the good source to me to understand structure of Accessibility APIs :)