# Resize windows Event

Tags: swift, cocoa

I'm creating a simple OS app but I cannot find anywhere how to take the resize event.

Let's assume that I wanna print the new width and height and I have this controller:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
        didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}
```

What i have to add? Thank you.

My question is not the same as [Listen for window resize event in Swift / Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34169365/listen-for-window-resize-event-in-swift-objective-c). Since my View have to extend `NSViewController` and not `NSWindowController`. This in his answer he did not explain what `windowWillResize` has to return exactly

Comment: No it is not, his code does not work!

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4 - macOS 10.13**

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {

    override func viewDidAppear() {
        view.window?.delegate = self
    }

    func windowDidResize(_ notification: Notification) {
        // This will print the window's size each time it is resized.
        print(view.window?.frame.size)
    }
}
```

Comment: Please note that this is 'viewDidAppear' not viewDidLoad, which gets called _before_ the WindowController's windowDidLoad and thus does not work. (I have no idea why it never occurred to me to make the viewController the Window's delegate. This simplifies matters.)

Answer (score 9):

You need to implement `NSWindowDelegate` somewhere, and set the window's delegate to that object. If you want, you could implement this code in your view controller.

```
class ViewController: NSViewController, NSWindowDelegate {
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        self.view.window.delegate = self
    }

    func windowWillResize(sender: NSWindow, toSize frameSize: NSSize) -> NSSize {
        // Your code goes here
    }

    func windowDidResize(notification: NSNotification) {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

Comment: self.view.window is nil

Comment: I thought the window would have been hooked up by then - perhaps try the code in viewDidAppear.