# What is your favorite disassembler tool in Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, assembly, disassembly, nm, otool

I am using the `otool`, `nm` and `Fraise` text editor to disassemble the `Mach-o` binaries. My workflow at this point is pretty straightforward:

  1. List the existed symbols.

```
nm -g
```

  2. Get the disasm code.

```
otool -vt
```

  3. Copy and paste this output to a text file.

  4. Read and comment the code in the text editor :)

I am looking for the tools that simplify the working with disasm code on `Mac OS X`.

Comment: Just a note for anyone reading this that `otool -Vt` will give you symbols for operands, e.g. `callq _main` rather than `callq 0x100001060`.

Answer (score 35):

You might want to try

- [Hopper Disassembler](http://www.hopperapp.com/),
- [osxdbg](http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/osxdbg),
- [Machoview](http://sourceforge.net/projects/machoview/),
- [otx](https://github.com/x43x61x69/otx) (otool GUI)
- and [Affinic Debugger GUI](http://www.affinic.com/?page_id=109).

Answer (score 16):

I als know of http://www.hopperapp.com/, but never used it.
(cannot be compared to Ida(Pro))

Comment: Much respect for mentioning hopper - I hadn't heard of it until I read your post. After playing with the trial for 5 minutes I was easily convinced to purchase. Thanks for turning me on to it.